# Draw More Arc Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

**Hello People** I'd Like to Know How to Draw More Arc Inside My Canvas, What I Need to Draw This circles:

[image]

So I Write This Responsive Code to Make my Canvas is Responsive:

```js
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = myCanvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = myCanvas.height / 2;
    var borderWidth = 20;
    var borderColor = '#2DC36A';
    var radius = (myCanvas.width / 2) - (borderWidth / 2);
    // days arc canvas background
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = borderColor;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    // Make Canvas Responsive
    function makeResponsive() {
        var containerWidth = $('.progress-nested').width();
        $('.progress-nested').height(containerWidth);
        var canvasElements = ['#myCanvas'];
            $('#myCanvas').width(containerWidth).height(containerWidth);
    }
    makeResponsive(); // Make Canvas Responsive in Document ready
    $(window).resize(function () {
        makeResponsive(); // Make Canvas Responsive in Window Resize
    });
```

```css
#progress {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.progress-nested{
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50%;
}
canvas {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    
<div id="progress">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="progress-nested">
                        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Note:** Please Run Code Snippet In Full Page

Comment: you might find this easier by using svg and styling the 'stroke-dasharray' with jquery: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dasharray/